# Подгрузка Javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

У некоторых клиентов нет доступа к библиотеки яндекс карт, и этот скрипт не подгружается.

```
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?key=xxxxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx==" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обработать эту ситуацию и изменить поведение в зависимости от доступности скрипта?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет документация: глава «[Готовность API](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/dg/concepts/load.xml#api-ready)». Вообще, советую вам переходить на API второй версии. Там и ключа не нужно.

По поводу отслеживания: вот [наиболее простой способ](http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror), используйте события onload и onerror.

Comment: Спасибо большое за вторую ссылку!